# How can I configure multiple buttons with one function in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def changeColour():
    LT.configure(bg = "white")
    LM.configure(bg = "white")
    LB.configure(bg = "white")

LT = Button(root, width=16, height=8, bg = "blue", command = changeColour)
LT.place(x=10, y=10)

LM = Button(root, width=16, height=8, bg = "red", command = changeColour)
LM.place(x=10, y=150)

LB = Button(root, width=16, height=8, bg = "green", command = changeColour)
LB.place(x=10, y=290)
```

How do I write the function `changeColour()` so it changes the colour of the button without a line configuring each button to change colour explicitly?

Comment: `for button in (LT, LM, LB):`?

Comment: I've a lot more buttons than I've shown here and was hoping for a neater solution than a loop like that

Comment: However many you have, surely the easiest way is to have a sequence of them (e.g. add each one to a list as you create it) then iterate over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming by "so it changes the colour of **the** button", you want only the button that was actually clicked to change color.

I know of two approaches.

1. Use lambdas to supply the name of the clicked widget to the function.

```
def changeColour(widget):
    widget.config(bg="white")

#...

LM = Button(root, width=16, height=8, bg = "red", command = lambda: changeColour(LM))
LM.place(x=10, y=150)
```

2. Use `bind` instead of `command`, as the former can deduce what widget raised the event.

```
def changeColour(event):
    event.widget.config(bg="white")

#...

LT = Button(root, width=16, height=8, bg = "blue")
LT.bind("<1>", changeColour)
LT.place(x=10, y=10)
```